# ssh-add does not see PGP key

Tags: ssh, gnupg, yubikey

I have my PGP key on my YubiKey and it works well on my MacBook, but it isn't working correctly on my Ubuntu 18.04 laptop. I am able to use `gpg --card-status` and it correctly shows the key along with the public data from my key ring, but `ssh-add -l` does not list anything. I am also able to sign data using `gpg --clearsign`. I have included my gp-agent.conf and scdaemon.conf files below.

gpg-agent.conf

```
default-cache-ttl 600
max-cache-ttl 7200
enable-ssh-support
```

scdaemon.conf

```
reader-port Yubico Yubikey
```

gpg --card-status

```
Reader ...........: Yubico Yubikey 4 OTP U2F CCID 00 00
Application ID ...: D2760001240102010006050203140000
Version ..........: 2.1
Manufacturer .....: Yubico
Serial number ....: 05020314
Name of cardholder: [not set]
Language prefs ...: [not set]
Sex ..............: unspecified
URL of public key : https://keybase.io/x/x.asc
Login data .......: [not set]
Signature PIN ....: not forced
Key attributes ...: rsa2048 rsa2048 rsa2048
Max. PIN lengths .: 127 127 127
PIN retry counter : 3 0 3
Signature counter : 44
Signature key ....: 
    created ....: 2017-12-27 19:26:18
Encryption key....: 
    created ....: 2017-12-27 19:33:31
Authentication key: 
    created ....: 2017-12-27 21:42:43
General key info..: sub  rsa2048/ 2017-12-27 Some Person <x@x.x>
sec#  rsa4096/  created: 2017-12-27  expires: 2019-12-27
ssb>  rsa2048/  created: 2017-12-27  expires: 2018-04-06
                                card-no: 0006 05020314
ssb>  rsa2048/  created: 2017-12-27  expires: 2018-04-06
                                card-no: 0006 05020314
ssb>  rsa2048/  created: 2017-12-27  expires: 2018-04-06
                                card-no: 0006 05020314
```